# Do C++ compilers make an independent decision about inlining a lambda function and its caller?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, inline

Consider the following function that uses a lambda.

```
void printAll( const std::vector< std::string >& strings )
{
    auto fn = [] ( const std::string& s )
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    };

    std::for_each( strings.begin(), strings.end(), fn );
}
```

Now it's clear that if inlining is enabled at all, the compiler will make a decision about whether to inline the `printAll()` function. (I'll forgo the derailing discussions of how it makes this decision, whether the presence or absence of the `inline` keyword has anything to do with it, "whole program" optimization systems and so forth.)

My question is how the compiler approaches the question of whether to inline `fn`. Does it:

- Inline `fn` iff it inlines `printAll()`?
- Always inline `fn`?
- Never inline `fn`?
- Make an independent decision about `fn`, essentially treating it as an entirely independent function?
- First decide about `fn` using the usual heuristics, then decide about inlining `printAll()` based on whether `fn` was inlined?

...or follow some other policy?

And is this answer dictated by the C++ specification or are compiler implementers free to answer it as they wish?

P. S. I know that `std::for_each()` takes its function argument as a template parameter and that templates bring their own complexities to the question of inlining. Unless I'm mistaken, this detail is incidental to the question, which has to do with how inlining decisions about lambdas and the functions that call them are made. Please don't let it distract you unnecessarily.

Comment: lambdas and template parameter functionoids are just functions with associated state, not that different from regular functions+global variables.  And since they're basically the same as any other functions, they ought to follow the same inlining policies as any other functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision of inlining the call to `fn` inside `printAll` is independent of the decision of inlining `printAll`. In particular, `fn` has very high chances of being inlined in all compilers, as is also the case of the `std::for_each`, but because `printAll` contains a loop (the one in `for_each`) likeliness of inlining drop in some compilers (some of the heuristics for inlining include the complexity of the code, and the presence of loops).

From the list of options, the best match is:

> First decide about fn using the usual heuristics, then decide about inlining printAll() based on whether fn was inlined?

Although there is an intermediate step missing on the inlining of `for_each` which is itself important for the heuristics.

Note that there are no guarantees in the standard regarding what compilers will do, so if you really care, look at the generated assembler